# Postresql Unique constrain isnt triggert

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

Iam using Django with Postresql. I am trying to create a model with 6 Constrains and 5 of them are working but the **UNIQUE** constrain somehow dosent get triggert.I looked into the generated Database but to my Eye it looks as intendet... dose some one spot my mistake?

Here is the genearted Table:

```sql
-- auto-generated definition
create table permissionentry
(
    id                serial    not null constraint permissionentry_pkey  primary key,
    permission_type   smallint  not null,
    source_group_id   integer
        constraint permissionentr_source_group_id_19769394_fk_usc
            references group
            deferrable initially deferred,
    source_profile_id integer
        constraint permissionentr_source_profile_id_54191816_fk_usc
            references profile
            deferrable initially deferred,
    target_group_id   integer
        constraint permissionentr_target_group_id_bb111301_fk_usc
            references group
            deferrable initially deferred,
    target_profile_id integer
        constraint permissionentr_target_profile_id_e97cadb4_fk_usc
            references profile
            deferrable initially deferred,

    constraint "constrainError.permissionExists"
        unique (source_profile_id, source_group_id, target_profile_id, target_group_id),

    constraint "constrainError.onlyOneSource"
        check (((source_group_id IS NOT NULL) AND (source_profile_id IS NULL)) OR
               ((source_group_id IS NULL) AND (source_profile_id IS NOT NULL))),
    constraint "constrainError.onlyOneTarget"
        check (((target_group_id IS NOT NULL) AND (target_profile_id IS NULL)) OR
               ((target_group_id IS NULL) AND (target_profile_id IS NOT NULL))),
    constraint "constrainError.groupsCantBeSupervisor"
        check ((source_group_id IS NULL) OR ((permission_type > 1) AND (source_group_id IS NOT NULL)))
);

alter table permissionentry
    owner to alamanda;

create index permissionentry_source_group_id_19769394
    on permissionentry (source_group_id);

create index permissionentry_source_profile_id_54191816
    on permissionentry (source_profile_id);

create index permissionentry_target_group_id_bb111301
    on permissionentry (target_group_id);

create index permissionentry_target_profile_id_e97cadb4
    on permissionentry (target_profile_id);

create unique index "constrainError.onlyOneSupervisorPerGroup"
    on permissionentry (target_group_id)
    where (permission_type = 1);

create unique index "constrainError.onlyOneSupervisorPerProfile"
    on permissionentry (target_profile_id)
    where (permission_type = 1);
```

And here is the model that generated this Table

```py
class PermissionEntry(models.Model):
    source_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='entry_source_profile'
    )
    source_group = models.ForeignKey(
        'Group',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='entry_source_group'
    )

    target_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        'Profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='entry_target_profile'
    )

    target_group = models.ForeignKey(
        'Group',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='entry_target_group'
    )

    permission_type = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=PERMISSION_TYPES,
        blank=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(source_profile__isnull=True, source_group__isnull=False) | Q(source_group__isnull=True,
                                                                                     source_profile__isnull=False),
                name='constrainError.onlyOneSource'
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(target_profile__isnull=True, target_group__isnull=False) | Q(target_group__isnull=True,
                                                                                     target_profile__isnull=False),
                name='constrainError.onlyOneTarget'
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['source_profile', 'source_group', 'target_profile', 'target_group'],
                name="constrainError.permissionExists"
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['target_group'],
                condition=Q(permission_type=1),
                name='constrainError.onlyOneSupervisorPerGroup'
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['target_profile'],
                condition=Q(permission_type=1),
                name='constrainError.onlyOneSupervisorPerProfile'
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(source_group__isnull=True) | Q(source_group__isnull=False, permission_type__gt=1),
                name='constrainError.groupsCantBeSupervisor'
            ),
        ]
```

To me the Table looks fine, but somehow it dosent work as intendet. The Databes allows me to insert two times the same row... this should not work, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so aparently the Unique-Constrain of Postgresql fails when there is a Null value in there. So my Solution is to write some custom SQL to create a constrain that has the needed behavior.

This is the SQL for the constrain

```sql
create unique index "constrainError.permissionExists" 
    on permission (
        coalesce(source_group_id, -1), 
        coalesce(source_profile_id, -1), 
        coalesce(target_group_id, -1), 
        coalesce(target_profile_id, -1)
    )
```

and i execute it in the Migration like this:

```py
migrations.RunSQL(
    'create unique index "constrainError.permissionExists" on permission (coalesce(source_group_id, -1), coalesce(source_profile_id, -1), coalesce(target_group_id, -1), coalesce(target_profile_id, -1))',
    'drop index "constrainError.permissionExists"'
)
```

The `coalesce()` Function inserts a -1 if the Value is `null` and so the constrain dosent break.